# Cannot Connect to SQS from EC2 With Temporary Credentials

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-sqs

I'm currently trying to connect to SQS from my EC2 instance within the same VPC and security group like the following. "dev-box" is the name of my IAM role name.

## Connect to SQS queue

```
    response = requests.get('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/dev-box')
    data = response.json()
    secret_key = data['AccessKeyId']
    access_key = data['SecretAccessKey']
    token = data['Token']

    sqs_conn = boto.connect_sqs(access_key, secret_key, security_token=token)
    q = sqs_conn.get_queue('test_queue')
```

The get_queue method throws a "Forbidden" exception, indicating "InvalidClientTokenId." I'm rather puzzled as to why this is happening. I've doubled checked my values several times with no success.

I should be able to just call boto.connect_sqs() with no params because I'm running from an EC2 instance, but that doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: correct, you should only need connect_sqs(). What do you get when you curl that endpoint? Also, please paste the role permissions used by this server.

Comment: I get an access key, secret key, and token. But I still get the error above. The permissions for the SQS queue are "Everybody."

Comment: I'm talking about permissions the other way 'round; in IAM/Roles, paste the appropriate Role Policy from the instance. It's okay to obfuscate account IDs.

Comment: Ah, I just realized there's no policy for SQS access...only one for S3. I presume one is needed?

Comment: yeah. To start, [use the "allow everything" policy from Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/UsingIAM.html#ExamplePolicies_SQS).

Comment: I just tried that- same thing. I'm getting a "403 Forbidden" along with "The security token included in the request is invalid" when I do a "get_all_queues" which is the same that I received prior. When I try to get the specific queue, it is returned as none.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQS code is generally correct. Please note that if you are running your code on an Amazon EC2 instance that has been assigned a Role, then the AWS SDK will automatically retrieve the credentials from the Meta-Data service.

Here's some code that worked for me from an EC2 instance. Note that I'm connecting to the Sydney region:

```
Python 2.6.9 (unknown, Sep 13 2014, 00:25:11) 
>>> import boto, boto.sqs
>>> q_conn = boto.sqs.connect_to_region("ap-southeast-2")
>>> q = q_conn.get_queue('cheese-queue')
>>> q
Queue(https://ap-southeast-2.queue.amazonaws.com/123412341234/cheese-queue)
```